# Bug in copying BTC address

Tags: blockchain.info, malware

I'm new here but I've been in the crypto world since 2016, today I'm going to tell you what just happened to me.
I had to send 25 euros to the address:
3Lch25qM9kKNEydEKKCKc2Em1naHBLN44y
After an hour from sending my BTC I still do not receive anything, so I decide to review the transaction and I was not believing what I saw .. a completely different address had been used to receive BTC and not giving an explanation I try to copy again and paste and I realized that that address changed once pasted. I'm not kidding, I'm not a scammer nor a liar, try also to copy and paste this address:
3Lch25qM9kKNEydEKKCKc2Em1naHBLN44y
and you'll end up with this:
3LP8AqQ5neyhGs9X5djjBBQ5RBBRCQ3LnY
https://www.blockchain.com/btc/address/3LP8AqQ5neyhGs9X5djjBBQ5RBBRCQ3LnY
Please help me

Comment: You should do a malware scan on you computer.

Comment: Are you using a recently updated version of Electrum?

Comment: So if you try to copy and paste the address remains the same? Can I try with windows defender or do you recommend something else?
I don't know if Stormgain has Electrum references as addresses but I don't think so

Answer (score 1):

It appears that your device is affected by malware. Likely, the malware detects when a Bitcoin address is in the clipboard and replaces it with an address owned by the malware creator.

Comment: Yeah you're right. I lost over 2BTC few months back. I did my research and apparently i had downloaded a media file with the malware attached so it monitored anytime bitcoin wallet addresses are copied to my clipboard. Its called a Wallet Address swapper.